# Какой уровень изоляции транзакция нужно использовать, чтобы параллельно вставлять записи?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Какой уровень изоляции транзакций нужно использовать, чтобы параллельно вставлять записи в одну таблицу из разных потоков или клиентских приложений?

В режиме, который используется по умолчанию, вторая транзакция ничего не может вставить пока не завершится первая.

Comment: в таблице есть первичный ключ, индекс, автоинкрементное поле? если да, то изменение уровня изоляции не поможет. Для массовых операций, вместо распараллеливания, нужно использовать класс BulkCopy.

Comment: @rdorn , именно так оно и есть. Т.е проблема в совокупности того, что вы перечислили или хотя бы что то одно уже не даёт применять другую изоляцию? Булк используется, но если пользователи запустят параллельно программу, то один будет ждать другого. В принципе, я уже отказался от транзакции и вычищаю мусор руками, но как можно было бы уйти от проблемы сохранив транзакцию?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093744/fastest-way-to-insert-in-parallel-to-a-single-table

Comment: как вариант: пользователь при загрузке данных формирует файл с данными определенного формата и отправляет его на сервер. На сервере с определенной периодичностью выполняется BULK INSERT из полученных файлов. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175937.aspx

Comment: @rdorn, оформите свои комментарии как ответ. Я сомневаюсь, что будет предложено что-то другое.

Comment: @rdorn и напишите, все таки совокупность 3 вещей вызывает проблемы или наличие хотя бы 1 из первого коммента?

Comment: Ну Bulk параллельно просто не работает, а при обычном insert происходит обновление индекса и вычисление автоинкрементных полей, поэтому при любом уровне изоляции проблема сохранится. В общем то, тут те же проблемы с одновременной записью, что и в любом многопоточном приложении. Читать и писать одновременно можно, а вот писать и писать - нет.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос, что проблема в параллельной работе клиентов, а не потоков.

Comment: _"В режиме, который используется по умолчанию, вторая транзакция ничего не может вставить пока не завершится первая"_ такого быть не должно, если таблица не блокируется каким-либо образом. Вообще bulk позволяет делать параллельные загрузки. Есть, однако, нюанс в использовании опции tablock. Если таблица - куча, и нет других индексов, то параллельные bulk-загрузки возможны (даже с tablock), обычные insert (а также иные DML- и DDL-операции) при этом, однако, блокирутся. Если есть индексы, то с tablock параллельные загрузки невозможны, без - возможны.

Comment: Уточню (а то как-то непонятно написал). Если опция tablock (которая при bulk-операции устанавливает на таблицу BU-блокировку) не используется, то параллельная загрузка данных возможна, и также разрешены иные DML-операции (ожидания при одновременных действиях тем не менее возможны). Если же происходит bulk-загрузка и опция tablock была указана, то в таблицу без индексов загружать данные параллельно другим таким же (с опцией tablock) bulk-ом можно (и кроме этого ничего больше нельзя), в таблицу с индексами - нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Если в таблице есть первичный ключ (кластерный индекс, опционально авто-инкремент) и/или другие индексы, то изменение уровня изоляции транзакций не поможет.

Есть три варианта для массового параллельного импорта данных в БД:

1. Клиент формирует файл данных для операции BULK INSERT, отправляет полученный файл на сервер и делает запись о загруженном файле в специальной таблице. Сервер, с некоторой периодичностью,выполняет скрипт, который проверяет таблицу и выполняет импорт полученных файлов. [Массовый импорт и экспорт данных (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms175937.aspx)
2. SQL Server умеет работать с XML. Достаточно таблицы с единственной колонкой типа XML, в которую вставляем данные для импорта в XML формате. Сервер, с некоторой периодичностью,выполняет скрипт, который проверяет таблицу и выполняет импорт полученных данных в основные таблицы.
3. Создать таблицу, структура которой копирует структуру целевой таблицы, но не содержит индексов и других ограничений (heap table). Импорт данных в эту таблицу производим с помощью класса [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx), а сервер, как и в предыдущих вариантах, централизованно переносит данные в основную таблицу.

По скорости варианты не сравнивал. По удобству - я бы предпочел первый или последний. Во всех случаях окончательный перенос данных в БД выполняет сам сервер или сервис, который обслуживает подключения клиентов, если соединение с базой не прямое.

Comment: теперь понятно, почему в оракле нет автоинкрементов и используются последовательности. печально, когда блокировка на всю таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

В статье, посвящённой [BULK INSERT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) говорится:

> A table can be loaded concurrently by multiple clients if the table has no indexes and TABLOCK is specified.

Простой ответ: на время загрузки удалить индексы, и указывать ключевое слово TABLOCK в операторе BULK INSERT.

Этот ответ даётся в [статье, посвящённой параллельному импорту данных](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186341(v=sql.105).aspx)

> Before a bulk-import operation, consider removing indexes from the table. For information about whether to keep or remove indexes, see [Guidelines for Optimizing Bulk Import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177445(v=sql.105).aspx).

По ссылке можно найти альтернативный способ оптимизации:

> To avoid dropping and re-creating indexes, you can perform a parallel import without specifying the TABLOCK hint. In this case, however, the multiple bulk-import streams can potentially block each other, and also, bulk logging optimizations are unavailable. To minimize blocking, you can specify a smaller batch size and use the ORDER hint to eliminate the sorting step during the bulk import operation.

То есть, не отключая индексы можно вставлять данные параллельно, но блокировки в этом случае возможны. Чтобы снизить их вероятность, надо посылать данные небольшими кусками и использовать ключевое слово ORDER.

Есть и другие способы ускорения этого процесса, с использованием NoSQL и MQ. И то, и другое можно использовать как временное хранилище, куда клиенты могут быстро сбросить данные. Переносом данных из временного хранилища в основную базу занимается фоновый поток, который выполняет вставку последовательно, и, естественно, никого не блокирует.